# How to pass certain key and value of a python dictionary to HTML script

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using flask and in one endpoint I just pass the following dictionary to html file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    q = {"id":23,
         "path": '/usr/test.py',
         "mynum": 22}
   return render_template("home.html", query=q)
```

in HTML file:

```
  {% for value in query.values() %}
     <td>{{ value }}</td>
   {% endfor %}
```

But in this way I am passing all the key-value's but I need to pass certain key-values. More clear, I expect such a solution in HTML if exist:

```
<td>{{ query["path"] }}</td>
<td>{{ query["id"] }}</td>
<td>{{ query["mynum"] }}</td>
```

I also tried this:

```
<td>{{ query.path }}</td>
<td>{{ query.id }}</td>
<td>{{ query.mynum }}</td>
```

but prints `query.path, query.id , query.mynum` rather than values

Comment: What is your expected output and what are you seeing?  I don't see an issue with the first method.

Comment: I am filling a kind of table so I expect ` /usr/test.py    23   22` be in a row as order you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Printing dictionary specific key's value in Jinja2 template without loop**

If you want to print specific key of a dictionary, you may use `.get()` method.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    q = {"id":23,"path": '/usr/test.py',"mynum": 22}
    return render_template("home.html", query=q)
```

`home.html`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Path</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ query.get("id") }}</td>
        <td>{{ query.get("path") }}</td>
        <td>{{ query.get("mynum") }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output:

[image: Dictionary key value in Jinja2 template]

If the key is not found in the dictionary it will print `None` as value. You may also pass default value as second parameter of the `get` method.

E.g.:

```
{{ query.get("arsho", "Value not found") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you are dealing with is that the order of the key/values in the dictionary is not the same order that you would like to display.  Instead of hard-coding the `<td>` elements, you can create a list of the keys in the order you want them to appear and pass that to the template.

```py
import jinja2

query = {"id":23,
         "path": '/usr/test.py',
         "mynum": 22}

ordered_keys = ('path', 'id', 'mynum')

h = '''<table><tr>
  {% for k in ordered_keys -%}
     <td>{{ query.get(k, '') }}</td>
  {% endfor -%}
</tr></table>
'''

t = jinja2.Template(h)

print(
    t.render(query=query, ordered_keys=ordered_keys)
)
# prints:
<table><tr>
  <td>/usr/test.py</td>
  <td>23</td>
  <td>22</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Would also your solution work in render_template()?

Comment: Yes.  You will to pass both variables as parameters